# Gradle fails to download external dependency from local artifactory which should be downloaded form mavenCentral

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

My gradle build fails due to an error from artifactory:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':PublishService:compile'.
> Could not resolve org.geotools:gt-wfs:9.0.
  Required by: 
      infraview_gradle:PublishService:0-SNAPSHOT > net.infraview:infraview_context:0-SNAPSHOT
      infraview_gradle:PublishService:0-SNAPSHOT > net.infraview:infraview_srv_masterdata:0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not HEAD 'http://beast:8082/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/org/geotools/gt-wfs/9.0/gt-wfs-9.0.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
```

The geotools artifact is not in my "libs-snapshot-local" - artifactory.

Why does gradle try to download is from there?

When I paste the request

```
http://beast:8082/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/org/geotools/gt-wfs/9.0/gt-wfs-9.0.pom
```

into the browser I get:

```
"message" : "The repository 'libs-snapshot-local' rejected the artifact 'libs-snapshot-local:org/geotools/gt-wfs/9.0/gt-wfs-9.0.pom' due to its snapshot/release handling policy."
```

Why does artifactory complain about "snapshot release handling policy" although this jar isn't in the artifactory in the first place?

Is this a gradle or an artifactory issue?

Comment: The artifact `org.geotools:gt-wfs:9.0` is obviously a _release_ artifact, not a _snapshot_ one. It really doesn't belong in a snapshot repo!

Comment: Yes, thats true. The strange thing is that I cannot find this artifact within the snapshot repository. And therefore I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it. There was another repo next to "libs-snapshot-release" in the artifactory which contained the jar.

Thanks for the comment.